# How would I list all entries regardless of section or structure?

Tags: entries, structure

I'm trying to build and XML site map that sorts all entries by their modification dates with the newly modified first.

`{% for entry in craft.entries.find() %}` ignores the structures,

`{% for entry in craft.entries.section().find() %}` returns the same as above,

`{% for entry in craft.entries.section('mainPages').find() %}` returns the structure as expected.

Looking for a way to include everything in a single, sortable query.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Actually your code should work just fine. But by default only 100 entries are fetched, maybe you need to increase the limit:

```
{% set entries = craft.entries.section().limit(null) %}
```

But if you just want to create a Sitemap, try [Ben Croker's Sitemap-Plugin](http://www.putyourlightson.net/craft-cms-plugins) (I really like it)

Comment: I’ve also released an open source plugin to generate sitemaps. https://github.com/joshuabaker/craft-sitemap

Answer (score 2):

This should output what you want:

```twig
{% for entry in craft.entries.order('dateUpdated desc') %}
    {{ entry.title }}
{% endfor %}
```

Although the easiest way to create an xml sitemap is to use the [Sitemap Plugin](http://www.putyourlightson.net/craft-cms-plugins).

Comment: I needed to add `elements` in the above query for it to work (Craft 3). `order('elements.dateUpdated desc')`

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the $49 plugin mentioned in other answers, there's also a more basic one that is free: https://github.com/xodigital/SimpleSitemap